# Split string on Upper Case word

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with 2 phrases, separated by an upper case word in the same string:

```
c="Text is here. TEST . More text here also"
```

I want to separate both phrases, removing the upper case word, `TEST` so that the output looks like:

```
["Text is here.","More text here also"]
```

What I did:

```
import re
c="Text is here. TEST . More text here also"
s=re.split('[A-Z][A-Z\d]+',c)
t=[re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]',' ',i) for i in s]
```

But I still get some unwanted spaces:

```
['Text is here  ', '   More text here also']
```

Is there a cleaner and pythonic way to generate `t` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> re.split('\s*[A-Z]{2,}[\s\.]*', c)

['Text is here.', 'More text here also']
```

Spaces (optional) followed by at least two uppercase characters, followed by spaces or dots (optional).

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it isn't that elegant.

```py
c="Text is here. TEST . More text here also"

In [20]: [i.strip().replace('. ','') for i in c.split('TEST')]

Out[20]: ['Text is here.', 'More text here also']
```